# Dymo JavaScript printing of barcode location

Tags: javascript, xml, barcode, dymo

I have an app that prints barcodes on a Dymo printer.  No problem.  I followed directions and created an XML file for printing parameters.  What I can figure out is how to place the barcode label under the text.  I have looked everywhere and cannot find anything.  Here is my XML:

```
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
  <DieCutLabel Version="8.0" Units="twips">\
<PaperOrientation>Landscape</PaperOrientation>\
<Id>Address</Id>\
<PaperName>30252 Address</PaperName>\
<DrawCommands>\
    <RoundRectangle X="0" Y="0" Width="1581" Height="5040" Rx="270" Ry="270" />\
</DrawCommands>\
<ObjectInfo>\
    <AddressObject>\
        <Name>Address</Name>\
        <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
        <BackColor Alpha="0" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255" />\
        <LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName>\
        <Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation>\
        <IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored>\
        <IsVariable>True</IsVariable>\
        <HorizontalAlignment>Left</HorizontalAlignment>\
        <VerticalAlignment>Bottom</VerticalAlignment>\
        <TextFitMode>None</TextFitMode>\
        <UseFullFontHeight>False</UseFullFontHeight>\
        <Verticalized>False</Verticalized>\
        <StyledText />\
        <ShowBarcodeFor9DigitZipOnly>False</ShowBarcodeFor9DigitZipOnly>\
        <BarcodePosition>Suppress</BarcodePosition>\
        <LineFonts>\
            <Font Family="Arial" Size="8" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
        </LineFonts>\
    </AddressObject>\
    <Bounds X="331" Y="150" Width="4470" Height="1215" />\
</ObjectInfo>\
<ObjectInfo>\
    <BarcodeObject>\
        <Name>BARCODE</Name>\
        <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
        <BackColor Alpha="0" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255" />\
        <LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName>\
        <Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation>\
        <IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored>\
        <IsVariable>False</IsVariable>\
        <Text></Text>\
        <Type>Code39</Type>\
        <Size>Medium</Size>\
        <TextPosition>None</TextPosition>\
        <TextFont Family="Arial" Size="6" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
        <CheckSumFont Family="Arial" Size="6" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
        <TextEmbedding>None</TextEmbedding>\
        <ECLevel>0</ECLevel>\
        <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment>\
        <QuietZonesPadding Left="0" Top="0" Right="0" Bottom="0" />\
    </BarcodeObject>\
    <Bounds X="331" Y="178" Width="4260" Height="320" />\
</ObjectInfo>\
```

'

Does anyone know of a parameter that will allow me to put the barcode under the address object instead above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have:

```
<BarcodePosition>Suppress</BarcodePosition>
```

Looks like you may need:

```
<BarcodePosition>BelowAddress</BarcodePosition>
```

--Hmm, what about changing your Y axis in the Bounds tag of your final ObJectInfo?

```
<Bounds X="331" Y="178" Width="4260" Height="320" />\
```

to

```
<Bounds X="331" Y="1365" Width="4260" Height="320" />\
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but that didn't seem to work.  Is there another parameter I can change?

Comment: OK, that did it, now to move it around a little to get it right!  Thank You!